# Going over a list of strings to find the string with the needed prefix

Tags: racket

I need to define the function `plPrefixContained` – that consumes 5 strings and
returns the first one that contains the string `"pl"` as a prefix – if one such
exists, and returns `#f` otherwise.

What I'm trying to do is to use the prefixes function to go over all the strings in the list and check their prefixes, put them in a new list and to output the first string as the result.
(I will handle the `#f` case later) my code is down below but it keeps giving me the error-

```
first: contract violation
  expected: (and/c list? (not/c empty?))
  given: '()
```

any help would be appreciated

```
(: plPrefixContained : String String String String String -> String)
(define (plPrefixContained x y z w v) 
  (list-ref (prefixes (list x y z w v) '()) 0))


(: prefixes : (Listof String) (Listof String) -> (Listof String))
(define (prefixes lis em)
  (cond
    [(and (eq? (string-ref (first lis) 0) "p") (eq? (string-ref (first lis) 1) "l"))
     (cons (first lis) em)]
    [else
     (prefixes (rest lis) em)]))
```

this is how I want my output to be like-for example

```
(test (plPrefixContained "yypl" "opl" "lpTT" "plpl" "lol")
      =>
      "plpl")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- intensional equality `eq?`, instead of extensional equality such as `equal?` or `string=?`
- comparing string / char, instead of comparing char / char or string / string

You are using `eq?`, which always makes me suspicious. `eq?` uses "intensional" equality, which is basically pointer equality, meaning that a string which is allocated somewhere in memory won't necessarily be `eq?` even if it has the same characters. You can see this with `(eq? "abc123" (string-append "abc" "123"))`.

If you're dealing with strings, lists, or any other data which "contains" things, you should avoid `eq?`. Instead you should use an "extensional" equality predicate such as `equal?`, or even better, a predicate specific to the types of values you expect, such as `string=?`. Here's how they behave better than `eq?`:

```
> (eq? "abc123" (string-append "abc" "123"))
#f
> (equal? "abc123" (string-append "abc" "123"))
#t
> (string=? "abc123" (string-append "abc" "123"))
#t
```

Since you're comparing using the strings `"p"` and `"l"`, I should be able to substitute `eq?` with `string=?` in your code:

```
(: prefixes : (Listof String) (Listof String) -> (Listof String))
(define (prefixes lis em)
  (cond
    [(and (string=? (string-ref (first lis) 0) "p") (string=? (string-ref (first lis) 1) "l"))
     (cons (first lis) em)]
    [else
     (prefixes (rest lis) em)]))
```

However, this reveals the second problem, which I only spotted after seeing the error message:

> ```
> string=?: contract violation
>   expected: string?
>   given: #\y
>   argument position: 1st
>   other arguments...:
>    "p"
> ```

The `string=?` isn't working because its first argument, the result of `string-ref`, is a character (like `#\y`), not a string. To fix this, use `char=?` instead of `string=?`, and compare with the characters `#\p` and `#\l` instead of the strings `"p"` and `"l"`.

```
(: prefixes : (Listof String) (Listof String) -> (Listof String))
(define (prefixes lis em)
  (cond
    [(and (char=? (string-ref (first lis) 0) #\p) (char=? (string-ref (first lis) 1) #\l))
     (cons (first lis) em)]
    [else
     (prefixes (rest lis) em)]))
```

Comment: first, thank a lot for the explanation! could you please tell me what might be the reason for char=?: unbound identifier in module in: char=? error?

Comment: What language are you working in? Is it `#lang racket`, `#lang typed/racket`, `#lang plai-typed`, `#lang pl`, or something else?

Comment: I'm using #lang pl

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure why `#lang pl` doesn't provide `char=?`. It provides both the types `String` and `Char`, and the predicate `string=?` for strings, but no `char=?` for chars. So it might just be something that slipped through the cracks when Eli was making it.